# preg_match_all and umlets

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am using preg_match_all to filter out strings

The string which I have supplied in preg_match_all is

```
$text = "Friedric'h Wöhler"
```

after that I use

```
preg_match_all('/(\"[^"]+\"|[\\p{L}\\p{N}\\*\\-\\.\\?]+)/', $text, $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

and the result i get when I print $arr is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => friedric
            [1] => h
            [2] => w
            [3] => ouml
            [4] => hler
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => friedric
            [1] => h
            [2] => w
            [3] => ouml
            [4] => hler
        )

)
```

Somehow the ö character is replaced by ouml which I am not really sure how to figure this out

I am expecting following result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Friedric'h 
            [1] => Wöhler
        )

)
```

Comment: Have you tried [`explode(" ", $text);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)?

Comment: preg_match_all is used to  filter out only the strings allowed in regex pattern.

Comment: I suspect that isn't really your literal text, and what you've actually got is an HTML entity encoding, e.g W&ouml;hler http://ideone.com/775SdG

Comment: @PaulDixon Yes you were right....These calls were coming through ajax and in a code piece htmlentities() function was used. I changed that to htmlspecialchars() and it started working...thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per nhahtdh's comment:

```
$text = "Friedric'h Wöhler";
preg_match_all('/"[^"]+"|[\p{L}\p{N}*.?\\\'-]+/u', $text, $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
echo "</pre>";
```

Gives

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Friedric'h
            [1] => Wöhler
        )

)
```

Comment: it does not print the result as indicated by you, it is still as follows   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => friedric'h
            [1] => w
            [2] => ouml
            [3] => hler
        )

)   problem is with "ouml" being put automatically

Comment: @KrishanGopal What is the result that you see? I copy and pasted this result from my computer.

Comment: @KrishanGopal **[u (PCRE_UTF8)](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)**:
This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern strings are treated as UTF-8. This modifier is available from PHP 4.1.0 or greater on Unix and from PHP 4.2.3 on win32. UTF-8 validity of the pattern is checked since PHP 4.3.5.

Comment: @KrishanGopal What is the version of PHP that you're using?

Comment: @nhahtdh Thanks. I was trying to find a way to prove it.

Comment: @Antony: By the way, you can simplify the regex a bit: http://ideone.com/V9TBPK since you are using single quote, and also you don't need some of the escapes in regex.

Comment: @Antony: PHP Version 5.3.8

Comment: I cloned your example to show how an HTML entity encoding would give the result the OP gets http://ideone.com/775SdG

Answer (score 0):

If you think `preg_match_all()` is messy, you could take a look at [pattern()](https://t-regx.com):

```
$p = '"[^"]+"|[\p{L}\p{N}*.?\\\'-]+';  // automatic delimiters
$text = "Friedric'h Wöhler";

$result = pattern($p)->match($text)->all();
```